# Inherit array with own type and stored properties in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, inheritance

Normally I have an array with `MemoryComponent` classes (so `[MemoryComponent]`). I'd like to refactor that to a custom array class, which has an element type of `MemoryComponent` and includes stored properties which the program can use.

I tried creating an extension, but it doesn't allow stored properties:

```swift
extension Array where Element: MemoryComponent {
    // ... no stored properties due to extension
}
```

I also tried creating another class for the array:

```swift
class StorageArray: Array<MemoryComponent> {
    // ... stored properties are possible
    // but there's an error because of this:
    // error: inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Array<MemoryComponent>'
}
```

How do I effectively create an inheritance from `[MemoryComponent]` to include stored properties?

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance, create a new class that has the array as a (private) property and then add your other properties and functions to access/modify the array. You could also let the array be public if you don’t need that kind of control of it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - That is a possibility, although built-in array methods aren't (directly) available in that context

Comment: I don’t think you have that many other options if you want to include your own stored properties

Comment: Is there an array-like protocol to create the class with?

Comment: Yes there is, check out the documentation for Array and see what it conforms to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to use composition for your case.

... but if a custom sort of `Array` is what you really want, there is actually a weird and not recommended option to hack that.

You can't inherit from `Array` since it's a `struct`. But you can implement the `Collection` protocol.

```
struct MemoryComponent {}

struct MemoryComponentsArray: Collection {
    
    // typealias all associatedTypes of `Collection` protocol
    typealias Element = MemoryComponent
    typealias Index = Array<Element>.Index
    typealias SubSequence = Array<Element>.SubSequence
    typealias Iterator = Array<Element>.Iterator
    typealias Indices = Array<Element>.Indices
    
    /// Your real data storage
    private let internalArray: Array<Element>
    
    /**
     Create any custom initializers you need
     */
    init(_ arrayLiteral: [Element]) {
        self.internalArray = arrayLiteral
    }
    
    // Implement `Collection` protocol core stuff
    // By referencing to internal array
    
    var startIndex: Index { internalArray.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { internalArray.endIndex }
    func makeIterator() -> Iterator { internalArray.makeIterator() }
    subscript(position: Index) -> Element { internalArray[position] }
    subscript(bounds: Range<Index>) -> SubSequence { internalArray[bounds] }
    var indices: Indices { internalArray.indices }
    var isEmpty: Bool { internalArray.isEmpty }
    var count: Int { internalArray.count }
    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        internalArray.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }
    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int, limitedBy limit: Index) -> Index? {
        internalArray.index(i, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: limit)
    }
    func distance(from start: Index, to end: Index) -> Int {
        internalArray.distance(from: start, to: end)
    }
    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        internalArray.index(after: i)
    }
    func formIndex(after i: inout Index) {
        internalArray.formIndex(after: &i)
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point, it's probably better to use a composition strategy rather than reimplementing most of the array methods

Comment: @Smally yes, that's right. Most of Array's functions are already implemented in the Collection protocol's extension. Depends on what methods of Array you need. The stuff I posted above is everything you're obligated to implement. Everything else is optional.